# How to send external messages to a specific channel with discord py?

Tags: asynchronous, discord.py, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to forward messages to channel when I receive messages from api.
I'm using

```
def trigger(messagecontent):
    async def messagesender():  
        channel = ... #get channel id  
        await channel.send(messagecontent)  
        await bot.close()

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        await messagesender()

    bot.run(token=Token)`
```

What happens is, when I receive message from api, I call `trigger(messagecontent)`, the bot logs in, sends message and closes, then the rest of my external script (sync version) executes.
But on the next loop, when new message from api is received, `trigger(messagecontent)` gives error
`Runtime: Session is closed`
If I don't close the bot with `bot.close()`, my sync script will be stuck at discord part. This is why I need to close the bot.

I don't want to use webhooks because there are many channels where messages are to be sent using the same bot.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you shutting down the bot via await bot.close()?
Ofc you will get that error if you shut down the bot.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I call an API, do calculation on prices and send message to discord. There is some code then trigger function is called and then the rest of code should execute. If I don't put `bot.close()` then my script will get stuck at trigger function and the code after it won't run. Thanks.

Comment: Codeblock 1 to get x ---> trigger(x) ---> Codeblock 2 ---> Repeat